# AutoCompleteTextView does not populate from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView which I am trying to populate from an adapter created from values stored in Firebase. The id of the AutoCompleteTextView is medicineName
Here is my code

```
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Medicines")

    mRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot:DataSnapshot) {
            for (suggestionSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children)
            {
                val suggestion = suggestionSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String::class.java)
                adapter.add(suggestion)
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError:DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
    medicineName.setAdapter(adapter)
    medicineName.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, b ->
        if(b) medicineName.showDropDown()
    }
```

However, the AutoCompleteTextView does not populate with this. The structure of the Firebase data is as follows:

[image]

Comment: I checked the same. The list of medicines is pretty long. Around 20K data points. It seems medicineName.setAdapter(adapter) is called before the for loop is complete. Hence the list remains empty

Comment: See also [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)